# Why can I not have a custom list button link to this Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, related-list

I'm currently trying to recreate the the functionality of the "Add Product" list button for Opportunity Products. I understand Visualforce pages need to have their controller set to the object they are modifying and this one is supposed to modify the Opportunity_Package__c object.
When I go to add the custom list button it all seems okay but this Visualforce page will not show as an available option to use and I'm not sure why.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity_Package__c" extensions="MetadataPackageEditor">
      <apex:form >
          <span>Opportunity </span>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity_Package__c.Opp_Package_Rel__c}"/>
          <apex:pageBlock title="Select Package(s)">
          <apex:pageMessages />

          <table style="width:100%;">
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">Select </th>
                      <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">Package</th>
                      <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">Products</th>
                      <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">PPU Discount</th>
                      <th style="border-bottom: medium solid black; border-right: medium solid black;">Expiration Date</th>
                  </tr>

                  <apex:repeat value="{!packageMap}" var="oppPackage">
                  <tr>
                      <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:inputCheckbox /></td>
                      <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:outputField value="{!packageMap[oppPackage].Name}" /></td>
                      <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:outputField value="{!packageMap[oppPackage].Products__c}"/></td>
                      <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:outputField value="{!packageMap[oppPackage].PPU_Discount__c}" /></td>
                      <td style="border-bottom: thin solid black; border-right: thin solid black;"><apex:outputField value="{!packageMap[oppPackage].Expiration_Date__c}"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  </apex:repeat>
              </tbody>
          </table>
          <apex:commandButton value="Add Packages"/>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
          </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you trying to override the add product button or recreate with a new custom button?  If the former the standard controller must be opportunity product and your additional logic in an extension.

Comment: No, I'm trying to mirrored that functionality.
The object this is being mirror onto is a custom Junction object named Opportunity_Package__c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a page to be a valid *related list* target, you must also use the `recordSetVar` attribute, which has the effect of changing the page's extensions to use an `ApexPages.StandardSetController` instead of an `ApexPages.StandardController`. This is what allows the page to be used on a related list. Without `recordSetVar`, it can only be used as a custom button or custom link (and, specifically, *not* a custom list button).

Comment: Any idea why I might now be getting the following error after only adding the recordSetVar and setting my extension to allow it?

Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!Opportunity_Package__c.Opp_Package_Rel__c}'. <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Comment: @CodyBeaner Yes, you'll need to write quite a bit of logic to support the change. I'm not a big fan of recordSetVar myself, but that's the platform's requirements.